# Autocompletion Plugin Visual Studio Code insert string in a grey color

Tags: visual-studio-code, plugins, vscode-extensions

I am trying to develop a plugin for VS-code that automatically performs autocompletion for java code.
Through the use of a neural network the plugin is going to analyze the all file and return a single code suggestion (for example of an entire method).

I don't want my suggestion to appear in the list of suggestions already provided by vs code, instead I would like my suggestion to appear in a light grey color in the editor like in this picture:

[image]

As you can see in this picture you have that string ("You, a few seconds ago...") that appears in the editor as if it is something external to the code itself.

Is there an API method to do such thing?

Thank you

Comment: in the GitLens extension find out how `gitlens.toggelLineBlame` works

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution:

```
// this is the object you use to define the type of decoration you want
const completionSuggestionDecoration = window.createTextEditorDecorationType({
    // remove all the decorations from the text
    textDecoration: 'none',
    // show the suggestions in light grey
    color: '#606060',
});

// this function writes some code to a file and then it applies the decoration to it 
function showSuggestion() {
    code = "this.c = 10;"
    decorationArray = []
    // we want to show the decoration from line 0 character 0 to line 0 character 20
    decorationRange = new vscode.Range(new vscode.Postion(0,0), new vs.codePosition(0, 20);
    decorationArray.push(decorationRange)
    
    // open the current document, insert the code at position 0,0 and then apply the decoration
    vscode.window.showTextDocument(editor.document, 1, false).then(e => {
        e.edit(edit => {
            edit.insert(new vscode.Position(0,0), code)
            })
    }).then(() => {
        // (variable 'editor' defined outside this function)
        editor.setDecorations(completionSuggestionDecoration, decorationArray)
    });
}
```